# Is there a default style.css

Tags: css

I'm handcrafting an extremely simple wordpress site, with minimum features, functions, templates etc.
Is there a default style.css that I can use as starter?
I have found [this one](https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS) but it is quite old - refers to WordPress 2.6. Should I use this?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use it, but it is not going to cover everything. Plus a lot of the style is going to depend on how you structure your content and other such items like your menus.

If you are looking for just a blank stylesheet that contains all the default classes and such that WordPress uses in outputting the content, there is [an article on CCS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/back-basics-wordpress-css-understanding-native-classes/) that has a pretty comprehensive list.

One thing I would advise is learning SASS to help you write your CSS faster and also develop a workflow that can be ported from site to site. It also has some nice time savers like calculations and variables (e.g. $baseColor: #0000ff; background-color: $baseColor)

Answer (score 1):

CSS and HTML came a very long way since Wordpress 2.6, so did Wordpress itself. The file that you are linking to is in all propability useless now due to a thousand changes over the years since the years of Wordpress 2.6.

There a quite a lot of [minimalistic starter themes](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&redir_esc=&client=tablet-android-samsung&source=android-browser-type&v=141338691&qsubts=1441731926874&action=devloc&q=minimilistic%20base%20themes%20wordpress) available which you can use to build a theme on which will actually be faster than building a teme from scratch. IMHO, it is quite insane to start a theme from absolute scratch, but that is just my opinion :-)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately the "minimalistic" in those themes refers to the layout than the code. It is real hard to find contemporary themes with minimal code and without scripts. Maybe its crazy to start from scratch - I'm not sure yet I can pull it off.

Comment: What I usually do is to strip out all irrelevant stuff that I don't need. Remember, you can delete everything you don't need, for example templates. You can delete all templates, you just need index.php to have a working theme. Believe me, it is easier deleting stuff you don't need than to code a theme from absolute scratch ;-)